# urllib request returning 403 error. How to rectify?

Tags: python, urllib

```
url_csv = "example_url"
local_path_csv = "./example.csv"
_ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_csv, local_path_csv)
```

Example of output:

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

[The HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is an HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden.

So the requested resource is just blocking your request. You should specify the real URL for further investigation.

But the first step you should do is to specify headers in your request like this

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

url_csv = "example_url"
local_path_csv = "./example.csv"
_ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_csv, local_path_csv)
```

Comment: its part of a test - the instructions says to simply run the above code... so should i contact the organisation to grant me permission to the resource?